# jpa-derby Boolean merge

Tags: jpa, derby

am working with JPA(EclipseLink) and Derby. In my object there is a boolean field. Before a merge operation, the field is set to true. but after the merge,  the field still holds the false value.

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class SleepMeasure extends AbstractEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1361849156336265486L;

    ...
    private boolean WeatherDone;

    public boolean isWeatherDone() { // I have already tried with the "getWeatherDone()"
        return WeatherDone;
    }

    public void setWeatherDone(boolean weatherDone) {
        WeatherDone = weatherDone;
    }   
    ...
}
```

It doesn't seem to matter whether, I use "getWeatherDone()" or "isWeatherDone()".

using code:

```
public class WeatherDataCollectorImpl{
    ...
    private void saveMeasures(WeatherResponse mResponse, SleepMeasure sleep) throws Exception {

        AppUser owner = sleep.getOwner();
        ...
        sleep.setWeatherDone(Boolean.TRUE);
        reposService.updateEntity(sleep,SleepMeasure.class);
    }
    ...
}
```

And here is my repository class

```
    public class RepositoryImpl{
    ...
    public <T extends AbstractEntity> T updateEntity(T entity, Class<T> type) throws RepositoryException {
        openEM();
        EntityTransaction tr = em.getTransaction();

        try {

            tr.begin();
            {
                // entity.weatherdone has value true
                    entity = em.merge(entity);
                // entity.weatherdone has value false
            }
            tr.commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            tr.rollback();
        }

        return entity;
    }
    ...
}
```

JPA console Info: There is no error, nor warning and not even any info that the boolean column shall be updated.

```
--Merge clone with references com.sleepmonitor.persistence.entities.sleep.SleepMeasure@b9025d
...
--Register the existing object  // other objects
...
--Register the existing object com.sleepmonitor.persistence.entities.sleep.SleepMeasure@1ba90cc
```

So how do I solve this small problem.

Note:
Derby defined this field as "SMALLINT".

thanks.

Comment: Show us the complete code of the entity.

Comment: what does the log say? you know, look at the SQL invoked ...

Comment: @JB Nizet, I have updated my question with the most important parts of my code.

Comment: @Neil, I have also pasted the JPA comments about the object "SleepMeasure" to be updated. There is no error, or warning and not even any information that the colum shall be updated.

Comment: why is your variable starting with UPPER case? Standard Java Beans implies "weatherDone" and getWeatherDone/setWeatherDone

Comment: @Neil, that was a typing error, but correction does not solve the problem. thanks

Comment: Perhaps you aren't committing your transaction? Perhaps you **are** commiting, but you aren't refreshing your Java objects from the DB, and so you're seeing stale values?

Comment: Oh God! I found my problem. While trying to complete a bideirection referencing, I stupidly did this in a setter property instead of an addMethod() . So I ended up with the referenced entity over-writing the updates on  the owning entity just before a merge. That was very defficult to find, and I think have learned a big lesson from it.  Thanks to all who tried to help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh God! I found my problem. Actually I realised, it was not only the boolean field, but the whole object could not be updated.
While trying to complete a bideirection referencing, I stupidly did this in a setter property instead of an addMethod() .

```
public void setSleepProperties(SleepProperties sleepProperties) {
    this.sleepProperties = sleepProperties;
    if (!(sleepProperties == null)) {
        this.sleepProperties.setSleepMeasure(this);
    }
}
```

Instead of:

```
public void addSleepProperties(SleepProperties sleepProperties) {
    this.sleepProperties = sleepProperties;
    if (!(sleepProperties == null)) {
        this.sleepProperties.setSleepMeasure(this);
    }
}
```

So I ended up with the referenced entity (sleepProperties.sleepMeasure) over-writing the updates on the owning entity just before a merge. That was very defficult to find, and I think have learned a big lesson from it. Thanks to all who tried to help me out.

The "addMethod()" solved my problem.